# deleting a Dynamic nested element in JSON message using Java Script

Tags: javascript, json

We are looking for a sample code to delete the nested element in JSON message using Java Script. This element name will be getting dynamically from other function.

Path to delete :

```
privateNetwork.floor.block.network.name
```

We are sure the following will work on hard coding:

```
delete jsonobj[privateNetwork][floor][block][network][name]
```

But how to achieve this for a dynamic scenario.
e.g: in the second try if we need to delete `privateNetwork.floor.room`.

Answer (score 1):

Split your property name into an array, loop over it until you find its immediate parent (next to last item) and use that to delete the innermost field (the last item of the array)

```
var deepObject = {
  privateNetwork: {
    floor: {
      room: 'Room 1408'
    }
  }
}

// Find object property recursively by string path
var deepFind = function (obj, path) {
  var current=obj; 
  path.split('.').forEach(function(p){ current = current[p]; }); 
  return current;
}

var dynamicPropertyName = 'privateNetwork.floor.room';

var innermostObjectName = dynamicPropertyName.substring(0, dynamicPropertyName.lastIndexOf('.'));
var fieldName = dynamicPropertyName.substring(dynamicPropertyName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

var innermostObject = deepFind(deepObject, innermostObjectName);
delete innermostObject[fieldName];

console.log(deepObject);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7r6avpsy/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you mean to try the following

delete jsonobj[privateNetwork.floor.block.network][name]

Comment: Not exactly. I added code and a JSfiddle. Check the console tab of firebug in the jsfiddle for the output.

Comment: hi Anders, this solution work like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please approve the answer :-)